# How to set bootstrap alert close button?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Here's the problem, the close button is not showing like it should be on right side (not like button). Can anyone please help me to figure this out.

```
<div class="alert alert-info alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
<%= notice %>
<button type="button" class="close alert-info" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
<span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
</button>
</div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WmUfg.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- CSS only -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-iYQeCzEYFbKjA/T2uDLTpkwGzCiq6soy8tYaI1GyVh/UjpbCx/TYkiZhlZB6+fzT" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-u1OknCvxWvY5kfmNBILK2hRnQC3Pr17a+RTT6rIHI7NnikvbZlHgTPOOmMi466C8" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<button type="button" class="btn-close" aria-label="Close"></button>
```

Comment: ok it helps, but another problem occur is that the cross button is not working. I mean it's not closing the alert bar by clicking on it.

Comment: Please check whether the bootstrap js file loaded or not by inspecting the website.

Comment: Is there any error showing in console?